# Why is my bitcoin node not picking up transactions?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

Im running a very simple bitcoin core node that talks to a client. Whilst running on the testnet everythign works perfectly. As soon as I switch to live, the bitcoin node no longer seems to pickup transactions for payments into addresses it generates. I double checked the payments with blockchain.info and the payments were received and confirmed. Anyone know what is going here?

```
bitcoin.conf

prune=600
maxconnections=10
rpcthreads=2
rpcuser=#######################
rpcpassword=#############################
daemon=1
keypool=10000
walletnotify=############################
blocknotify=##########################
testnet=0
rpcallow=###############
```

The same config and was used for test/live with the obvious exception of toggling the testnet value.

Comment: Define "pick up"?

Comment: Did you wait for it to acquire the entire blockchain? Is it acquiring blocks?

Comment: David, you hit the nail on the head. Block acquisition was crazy slow. Fixed that issue now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that Bitcoin core had not finished downloading all blocks. It was running extremely slow. After allowing more connections everything sorted itself out overnight.